# Remove both same values from c++ stl list

Tags: c++, stl, linked-list, duplicates, iteration

I have a list like

```
2 , 6 , 6 , 8 , 9
```

I want this like

```
2, 8 , 9
```

I wrote a code

```
for(std::list<int>::iterator i = almostPrimeList.begin(); i != almostPrimeList.end(); ++i) {
  for(std::list<int>::iterator j = ++std::list<int>::iterator(i); j != almostPrimeList.end(); ++j) {
        if(*i == *j) {
            cout <<*i << " found";
            //almostPrimeList.remove(*i);
            break;
        }
  }
}
```

it appears found the values which has duplicate, but when I want to remove it make an infinite loop

Comment: Oh ! I could have  use STL::Set data structure to avoid duplicate data on a list ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you erase the element pointed by i or j then the iterator becomes invalid.

Try:

```
++j ; // move to next
almostPrimeList.erase(i, j) ; // element pointedby j won't be rased
i = j ; // ok, reinitialize i
break ;
```

Comment: Oh I see.. very sharp explanation Thanks !